# How to respond to a specific client when accepting a connection with the Winsock control

Tags: vb6, winsock

I've been building a chat client server/client application. I've gotten most things working good except for one thing I can't seem to figure out. When a client tries to connect to the server I want the server to check a listbox to see if the user exists. If the user doesn't exist, proceed like normal, but if it does exist, then send a packet or something back to that client only saying the username is already taken to please choose another.

A couple of ways I have thought of doing this, but not sure if they are the best way.

1. Create a second Winsock control on a separate port have the client connect to that port first check username, then connect to the other port to join the chat. The only problem I can see with this approach is if multiple people connect to this Winsock at the same thing I'm still addressed with the same issue as using the original Winsock.
2. Create variables with the index number that has currently asked for a connection and another to hold the username. After checking the user list use the variables to identify the client and send the data to that client only.

I'm kind of new to Winsock programming so this might be something really easy and I'm making it extremely hard. I need some insight, maybe even some examples would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

To do anything with a socket, you must accept it first. Generally, you have a single listening sockets and a list of "spare" sockets. When you accept a connection, you pass it over to one of the spare sockets which then does any work for that client only.

TL:DR; Accept all connections then when you receive the name, respond as needed, maybe disconnecting them or asking them to try again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was making it way harder then it needed to be I figured it out on my own. Winsock(Index) is always going to be the current sock that just connected. Instead of creating a new winsock to do the check I just did the check on the current winsock then sent the reply back to winsock(index). I don't know why I always over think stuff. Make things way more complicated then they need it be.